# German marriage query for Anna Waltraude ENSFELDER born Hamelin

Tags: germany, 20th-century, marriage-records

From family Stammbuch Anna Waltraude ENSFELDER was born in Hamelin/Hameln, Germany in 1912. She had a daughter Ursula. Can anyone tell me who she married?

Answer (score 1):

Get in touch with Stadtarchiv Hameln (https://www.hameln.de/de/leben-in-hameln/bildung/stadtarchiv/) and the local civil registration office (Standesamt Hameln, https://www.hameln.de/de/buergerservice-verwaltung/buergeranliegen/standesamt/) and ask where the birth records from 1912 are kept. Get a copy and if she was married a side note should indicate time and place of marriage. Try to get the marriage record from there. If the suspected husband was the father of the daughter mentioned above, he should also be listed in the daughter’s birth certificate.

Always state your relationship and when the person of interest died. This might be helpful if privacy restrictions apply.

Comment: Belated thanks for your help. I'll certainly check this out.